# Are these two sentences same meaning?

Tags: meaning

Do the sentences

> I have **never been** so glad to see you.
>   I have **not been** so glad to see you

have the same meaning?

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic expression is

> **have never been so glad**

which means in all of one's experiences has one not felt such joy.

> **have not been so glad**

could potentially be qualified

> I have not been so glad to see *someone* **these past few weeks**.